# Alignment issue in users page while searching user

Tags: bug, design, search, users

There is an alignment issue occurred while searching the users in the [Users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users).

The grid cells' height is increased while fetching the result. Once the result fetched, the grid's height become normal, so the issue is due to the searching indicator, when it is visible.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: While search the users]

GIF for the same:

> [image: While search the users GIF]